# Python raw_input & Bazel: EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python, build, stdin, bazel

I am attempting to use Bazel as the build system for a python program. I'll use an example of test.py. My BUILD file includes:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
py_binary(
    name = "test",
    srcs = [
        "test.py",
    ],
    main = "test.py",
    deps = []
)
```

My test.py includes:

```
name = raw_input("Please enter your name\n")

print "your name is {}".format(name)
```

When I run though normal compiler I get:

```
Please enter your name
python
your name is python
```

However, when I run as bazel run :test
I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[directory]test.[directory]python_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    name = raw_input("Please enter your name\n")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
Please enter your name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of bazel are you using? In older versions of bazel, the bazel client doesn't connect standard in to the binary when run with `bazel run`. [In 0.12 and up](https://blog.bazel.build/2018/04/11/bazel-0.12.html) you can pass `--direct_run` to connect standard in. In [0.15 this became the default](https://blog.bazel.build/2018/06/26/bazel-0.15.html) and `--direct_run` is a noop.

You can also run the resulting binary itself (in your example if the build file is at the root of the workspace it would be `bazel-bin/test`)

Comment: I believe I'm on `0.7.3` :/ It's a required version at work too.

Comment: Running the file from bazel-bin worked for me! Thanks!